# loging to hazelcast management center is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: hazelcast

When I log in to Hazelcast management center  I get the following exception. Not sure what exactly is causing this issue.

The Management Center is deployed in Weblogic 12c

Hazelcast version: 3.1.3

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor534.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:282)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:226)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:177)
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.invokeMethod(DataService.java:108)
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.getResponse(DataService.java:86)
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.servlet.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891)
        at java.util.SubList$1.next(AbstractList.java:707)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:141)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:216)
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.WarningLogsManager.getSystemWarnings(WarningLogsManager.java:96)
        at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.showSystemWarning(DataService.java:717)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the code. The exception doesn't make any sense. Which JVM are you using. And perhaps it is smarter to run on a more lightweight container like jetty,tomcat etc.

Comment: Hi i am using jdk1.7.0. I tried running it on tomcat and it is working fine but weblogic is the only supported server in our organization.

Comment: I observe this issue only when i click on cluster home and when it tries to get members and partition information from there it repeats, so i am guessing its in a recurring thread. If i press other link's like the map section or member info the exception spitting stops, and all the rest works fine, so i am thinking this is something to do with the partition picture on cluster home page

Answer (score 2):

So finally this issue got resolved . I added the following preferred packages list to my weblogic.xml file because it was suggested by CAT tool .

```
<wls:package-name>javax.activation.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>javax.mail.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>javax.mail.event.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>javax.mail.internet.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>javax.mail.search.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>javax.mail.util.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
```

Removing those fixed the issue.